# Openvswitch failed to start when installing Pnetlab

Tags: proxmox

I have a problem when installing PNETLab in Ubuntu 18.04 container. I see openvswitch is failed to start. Even if I reinstall, the result is the same. Is there any adjusment on the network configuration side in the guest or host? thanks

Here the information of openvswitch-switch package

```
# apt install openvswitch -y
openvswitch-switch.service - Open vSwitch
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvswitch-switch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)    
Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 23 02:33:57 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for OpenvSwitch. 
Mar 23 02:33:57 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: openvswitch-switch.service: Job openvswitch-switch.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 23 02:39:31 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Open vSwitch.
Mar 23 02:39:31 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: openvswitch-switch.service: Job openvswitch-switch.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 23 02:49:48 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Open vSwitch.
Mar 23 02:49:48 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: openvswitch-switch.service: Job openvswitch-switch.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 23 03:02:13 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Open vSwitch.
Mar 23 03:02:13 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: openvswitch-switch.service: Job openvswitch-switch.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dpkg: error processing package openvswitch-switch (--configure):
 installed openvswitch-switch package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pnetlab:
 pnetlab depends on openvswitch-switch; however:
  Package openvswitch-switch is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pnetlab (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvswitch-switch
 pnetlab
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@pnetlab01:~# journalctl -xe
-- 
-- Unit ovs-vswitchd.service has begun starting up.
Mar 23 03:02:14 pnetlab01 ovs-ctl[77974]: modprobe: FATAL: Module openvswitch not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.11-8-pve
Mar 23 03:02:14 pnetlab01 ovs-ctl[77974]:  * Inserting openvswitch module
Mar 23 03:02:14 pnetlab01 ovs-ctl[77974]:  * not removing bridge module because bridges exist (docker0)
Mar 23 03:02:14 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: ovs-vswitchd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 23 03:02:14 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: ovs-vswitchd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 23 03:02:14 pnetlab01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Open vSwitch Forwarding Unit.
```

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* last year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.